# How to know if Android Device Manager's erase phone worked on a stolen device?

Tags: google, android-device-manager, lost-phone, remote-wipe

Phone was stolen, and when I went to wipe it in the Android Device Manager the phone appears off line for more than 5 days.

Today when i checked, the phone was no longer listed in my device manager, does this mean it was wiped, how can i confirm this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no confirmation provided that the device had been wiped as you can read in [Google Support](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18eBUqw2iKbYA/?hl=en) (there are are earlier references and this is the latest I could find - last month)

So you can't - the fact that device is wiped also means that your device is not associated with your account and therefore you cannot see it listed in your devices. Also as stated [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en)

> **Erase**
>   Permanently deletes all data on your device (but might not delete SD cards). After you erase, **Find My Device won't work on the device**

(Emphasis Supplied)

Not appearing in the devices list cannot be a confirmation by itself that the device is wiped ; since Google didn't cite this as proof, but yes, most likely it is wiped

Unless you installed a third party device manager app, which provides such confirmation , there is no way to get a confirmation